# Original DKIM signing is not sent when using SMTP relay

Tags: smtp, dkim, milter, relay

We are using a VPS (ubuntu 18, postfix) to send mails for multiple domains hosted on a server (AlmaLinux 8). For example from the domain "domain.com".

- VPS is `maildomain.com`
- Hosting server is `server.com`
- DKIM is setup in both VPS and Server.

When domain.com sends the mail DIRECTLY (without VPS) from the server, the mail is DKIM signed correctly by the Server.

But when domain.com sends it through the SMTP relay, the mail is DKIM signed ONLY by the VPS. The Server DKIM signature is not forwarded.

We need that the DKIM server signing to be transmitted by the VPS, to the final recipient. So the mail will have 2 DKIM signatures.

I think this is some problem with the Milter but cannot find out

```
# Milter configuration in main.cf
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are both server using the same key/signature/selector ? Why do you need both signatures ?

If you send with the same domain (let's say you send with user@maildomain.com) everytime using server.com for outgoing traffic : one signature should be ok.

It seems server.com is configured to send @maildomain.com with this own signature so it may remove the existing one...

Hope this answer will give you at least a clue.

Comment: We send for a few DOMAINS hosted on ONE SERVER. All mails are sent to the VPS that has its own hostname, different than the server's hostname.
All messages sent from all domains are DKIM signed by the VPS.
It works with yahoo outlook, gmail, etc.
But some regional (french) providers tell them that mails aren't DKIM signed, so we would like to have the 2 signatures, from SERVER for the sending domain, and from VPS.

Comment: does the domains send using the same selector for DKIM or different ? You can get much details about deliverability using tool like this one https://www.mail-tester.com/. Let me know how is your score and if you get some details about what could be improved. This because I'm pretty 100% sure you don't need DKIM on both servers to be well authenticated against providers.

Comment: Various selectors.
On mail-tester we of course always look, 10 points! For them, the mail IS DKIM signed, no problem.
The point is that only french providers are making problems, we begin to think they don't like the "material" inside the mails... Censorship, in other words... All non French, no problem!

Comment: Nobody?
From a french provider: "I'm in charge of postmaster role for SFR mail. I've found the trace of the reject hereunder. However I can confirm that there is an issue with the DKIM signature as the domain of the signer is not the one of the From header : [VPS domain] vs [Website domain]

Comment: This mean the truth is not in the DKIM signature but in the use of domain names between the vps and the relay : one of the two instances of postifx may be missconfigured (with the machine FQDN instead of the domain you are using) regarding the error message "domain of the signer is not the one of the From header "